# load test / stress test web services

Tags: web-services, load-testing, stress-testing

Does anyone know of a good tool to test load and stress on webservices? I've been looking at Watir and Selenium, but there more web page centered.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here are some common load testing tools:

- [HTTP_Load](http://www.acme.com/software/http_load/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)
- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [HTTPperf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf)
- [AB](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Comment: HTTPperf link is broken.

Comment: And which ones of them are good, and why?

Comment: only two of these actually support webservices, the rest are for actual websites

Answer (score 10):

You should definitly take a look a [SoapUI](http://www.soapui.org/).

Comment: Just in case someone may find this question again. SoapUI is pretty nice for load testing web service interfaces. Helped me a lot!

Comment: actually, SoapUI is pretty ... limited if it comes to loadtesting - its much more suited towards functional testing, interface testing and the likes. If you want to do LOAD tests you will need LoadUI. Just saying.

Answer (score 3):

I actually like [Pylot](http://www.pylot.org/)

It's free, open source, and I've been able to use it for a number of projects.

Comment: My program (free, open source, supports soap services): https://wuloadtester.codeplex.com

Comment: The site doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 2):

I've used [openSTA](http://www.opensta.org/).

This uses a relatively simple script language.

You can easily test web services and write your own scripts.

It allows you to put scripts together in a test in any way you want and configure the number of iterations, the number of users in each iteration, the ramp up time to introduce each new user and the delay between each iteration. Tests can also be scheduled in the future.

It's open source and free.

It produces a number of reports which can be saved to a spreadsheet. We then use a pivot table to easily analyse and graph the results.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Selenium and Watir were actually designed for load testing. Maybe you should be looking at things like httperf and ab.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [WebLOAD](http://www.radview.com) before for webservice testing