# How do you load/stress test a java servlet?

Tags: java, servlets, load-testing, response-time

I have a servlet, and I want to do more than a unit test. I need to know performance under load and stress test it.

I need to be able to script a variety of transactions that run over specific time frames, and get collect response time data so I can identify failure points and at what point responses severely degrade. I have been looking through SO for any answers, and found some information about HTTPUnit, but am not sure if this would be the solution to this question. Would appreciate very simple samples in your answers, if possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [load test / stress test web services](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351938/load-test-stress-test-web-services)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/).

Comment: I'll second using JMeter.  Try to give some variety to the inputs.  Caching can throw off your results significantly. Selenium might be interesting to you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://www.blitz.io. Works well for testing from the cloud if the app is accessible from the Internet.

Comment: Interesting solution to test public sites and high volume hits. But not quite what I need. The volumes appear overkill for my work, and cloud testing is not the area I'm working in.