# Best HTTP Performance and Scale testing tool to measure throughput and TTFB

Tags: performance, http, jmeter

I have been using apache Jmeter for evaluating HTTP performance and scale testing, but there are two problems I can see here:

1. JMeter in GUI mode is too slow and I am unable to ramp up to more than 100 connections per client. I had to switch to CLI mode and increase heapspace for JVM to more than 95% of my RAM to  scale up to 500 parallel connections. However, this is not significant and I am looking out better ways to improve this.
2. I am not finding appropriate JMeter listeners which can plot write throughput and read latencies (TTFB) for different variety of file sizes? Is there a better listener or Is there a better tool for me to use to improve on performance and measuring throughput and latencies?

Your valuable suggestions will be of great help!!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why dont you try jmeter client server model for increasing no of connections or use higher end machine and for plotting graphs, http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ExtrasSet/ find the plugin suitable for your need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WebStressTool (WCAT) (from Microsoft, I think).  From a Desktop client you will be limited to 10 concurrent connections (if you don't override the registry somewhere).  I think you can "coordinate" "drones" using the web stress tool, i.e. do the stress from multiple pc's.

Sample scripts below

Simple:

```
settings
{
    counters
    {
        interval = 10;
        counter = "Memory\\Available MBytes";
    }
}
```

More complex:

scenario

```
{

    warmup   = 30;
    duration  = 120;
    cooldown  = 100;

    transaction
    {

        id = “test”;
        weight = 1000;

        request
        {
        url = “/AAA_ST/Web/Index.aspx”;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also see: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/03/09/stress-test-asp-net-web-application-with-free-wcat-tool.aspx?Redirected=true .  The link could eventually go missing, but it is MSDN, so it should be there for some time.

Comment: Will WCAT tool provide me data on Read latency - TTFB and Write throughputs after the runs?

Comment: According to the official site (http://www.iis.net/downloads/community/2007/05/wcat-63-(x86)), it supports these:  "Supports Performance Counter integration" AND "Measures throughput and response time".  Using the performance counter queues counters, you should see at what point it starts having to "stop" servicing requests as the queue length will grow.

Comment: You should be able to run a script for different sizes and then log them for comparison.   I don't think it is unfathomable to consider that process scriptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just read << High performance MySQL >>, the writer introduce the test tool: http_load with some examples.
It seems simple to use for me

and find duplicate question:
[load test / stress test web services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351938/load-test-stress-test-web-services/351944#351944)